# Why does accelerating break the synchrony between two clocks?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration

The standard method for synchronizing two clocks is to exchange light signals between the them and ensure the satisfy the relation $t_A' - t_B = t_B - t_A$. This method works because both clocks can agree on the one way speed of light.
When two clocks are synchronized, they will remain synchronized so long as they remain in an inertial frame. Any acceleration will break the synchrony between the two clocks (as for instance, in the twin paradox). 
But why does synchrony fail in an accelerating frame?
Is the method for synchronizing clocks somehow invalid for accelerating objects? Do they disagree on the one way speed of light?

Answer (score 0):

The method used for synchronizing two clocks in Special Relativity is important because it allows us to build a general inertial frame<sub>1</sub> of reference, so that we can compare velocity and other physical quantities in different position of space.

One important detail is that, when we build a general inertial reference frame, we synchronize clocks that are **at rest with respect to us**.

In fact assume that we synchronize clocks that are in relative motion, after a while due to *time dilation* the clocks will stop being synchronized.

So yes: acceleration will break synchrony between two clocks, as relative velocity will also do.

---

1. I use the world "general" to specify the the frame of reference in question is not a *local* one.